# How to prevent magento from resetting my URL rewrites?

Tags: magento

I have the following magento categories...

Category A / Category B

In the Category B edit screen, there is a url key set to: category-b

By default the result on the front-end will be:

www.mydomain.com/category-a/category-b

So in the URL rewrite area, I changed this to redirect to:

www.mydomain.com/Category-B

It works just fine, but when I re-index the system, everything is reset. I lose my custom URL rewrite.

How can I enforce it so that it is not reset?

Answer (score 0):

You have edited magento system url rewrite. This changes are ignored by index.
To fullfill your needs you should create "custom" url-rewrite.
Then index will honor them and won't remove.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem I first made sure I was using 'Custom' option AND come up with my own UNIQUE ID NOT the same ID as the system sets for the categories